# Is it possible to put Higman group as an amenable by sofic group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, amenability, sofic-groups

I know [Higman group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman_group) has an amalgamated product decomposition of $BS(1, 2)$. Is it possible to decompose Higman group as some groups we are more familiar with. For example, is there a normal subgroup K of Higman group $H$ such that $K$ is amenable and $H/K$ is sofic?

Comment: Yes, I mean $K$ is amenable. Thanks for correcting!

Answer (score 6):

Higman's group is an amalgam $A\ast_C B$ and $C$ has index $\ge 3$ in both $A,B$. Hence an easy consequence (see Proposition 7 [here](https://www.normalesup.org/~cornulier/icc.pdf) if necessary) is that the amenable radical is contained in $C$.

Here $C$ is free on 2 generators, and has trivial radical. So the amenable radical of Higman's group is trivial. So the question is just equivalent to whether Higman's group is sofic, which is known to be open.

Actually, I think it's also open whether Higman's group admits a single nontrivial sofic quotient.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying! Can you specify what A and B are?

Comment: If $x_1,\dots,x_4$ are the standard generators, $A$ is generated by $x_1,x_2,x_3$, $B$ by $x_3,x_4,x_1$, and $C$ is freely generated by $x_1,x_3$.

Comment: Isn't it open whether there is *any* non-sofic group (much less Higman, much less a quotient)?

Comment: Yes, many people believe there should be a non-sofic group.

Comment: @IanAgol my point is that the known methods to prove that a group is sofic don't apply (or don't seem to apply) to any quotient of the Higman group. Yes existence of a non-sofic group is an open question but proving soficity results is interesting since it has various implications on its structure and dynamics.